# Error "operand should contain 1 column(s)" when using SET to calculate percentage in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I created table productivityByUser with columns user and avgEncHr (and more that aren't relevant). I am trying to calculate the percent of each avgEncHr and want to call that PercAvgEncHr. I only want to show all columns where PercAvgEncHr > 25.

I've tried a lot of different things like altering the table and column, etc. and it gives me error: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

```
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(user)
FROM productivityByUser);


SET @totalAvgEncHr = (SELECT SUM(avgEncHr)
FROM productivityByUser);

-- ALTER TABLE productivityByUser
--  ADD COLUMN PercAvgEncHr INTEGER;

SET @PercAvgEncHr = (
    SELECT avgEncHr, @totalAvgEncHr,(avgEncHr) / ((SUM(avgEncHr)) * 100)
FROM productivityByUser);


SELECT * FROM productivityByUser WHERE (PercAvgEncHr > 25);
```

Comment: `SET @PercAvgEncHr ...` is getting multiple values in return, it should get one.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @PercAvgEncHr = ( SELECT avgEncHr/ SUM(avgEncHr) * 100 FROM productivityByUser );
```

Now you store only one record. Hope it helps!